# Profiling and benchmarking TCP/IP connection software

Tags: networking, network-monitor, performance-analysis, benchmarking

Is there a good software to analyze the latency on TCP/IP (Ubuntu system) connection between two computers and Wireshark does not work for me.

The measurement needs to be benchmarked and defined. My problem is that the tests are inconsistent and difficult to reproduce because of some built in features. So I need software that allows some advanced features like probing the kernel calls to the network etc...

Comment: This sounds like a very good question; although I am sure that more detail would make it easier to help you. Welcome aboard! I hope that you get your answer (if Wireshark can't help, then I doubt that even [iperf](https://iperf.fr/) can - did you try it?

Comment: If you give me a hint what is ambiguous or too vague I will give my best to explain.

Comment: I don't really know, it was just general advice. Probing kernel calls sounds like advanced user stuff to me. Until now, I have gotten along fine with iperf

Comment: It is not madness with the right flags in perf you can do it, my idea is iPerf, tcpDump and iptraf. But i thought maybe someone knows something that I do not.

Comment: Here is a series of tools on github

(https://github.com/caesar0301/awesome-pcaptools)

Comment: Wow! that does look good. Thanks. I am particularly grateful for the indirect link to the list of awesome tools at https://github.com/sindresorhus/awesome